# $G$ and $H$ groups s.t. $Z(G) \cong Z(H)$. What about $G$ and $H$ themselves?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ and $H$ be nontrivial, nonabelian, noncenterless groups such that $$Z(G) \cong Z(H) \tag 1$$ Can we get from $(1)$ some insight about $G$ and $H$ themselves?

Motivation: for any $G$, $(1)$ should hold for $H=\Theta\Gamma$, $\Theta$ and $\Gamma$ being the homomorphic images of $G$ in $\operatorname{Sym}(G)$ induced by left and right multiplications.

Comment: Not sure what information you are looking for about these groups. For all $n\geq 3$ the center of $S_n$ is trivial. But what relation there is between $G=S_n$ and $G'=\{e\}$?

Comment: Please edit your question to something more specific. As is, there is really not much to answer. Maybe it could makes sense to focus more on what motivated you and/or to a priori restrict G and G'